# Issues with permissions in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

I have received really weird error while sync of replicas:

```
$ /usr/atria/bin/multitool syncreplica -import -receive

multitool: Error: Permission denied: not VOB owner or privileged user.
multitool: Error: Can not import into vob:/vobs/***, permission denied.

multitool: Error: INTERNAL ERROR detected and logged in "/var/adm/rational/clearcase/log/error_log".
multitool: Error: Permission denied: not VOB owner or privileged user.
multitool: Warning: Could not disable replay in vob: Operation not permitted.
```

Does anyone know what could be the root cause of the issue?
vobadm is owner of all files under `/usr/atria`.

Answer (score 0):

Being the owner for the file has nothing to do with being the owner of the vob.

Do a `cleartool descr -l vob:\yourVob` to see who the owner is (you might also have to use `multitool chreplica –npreserve`, as described in "[Preservation Mode](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/c_preservation_mode.htm)").

A [`cleartool protectvob`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protectvob.htm) can change the owner of a vob (make sure the vob is locked on all site, though, to [avoid race condition similar to this one](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK39919))

The Op confirms:

> the issues is resolved by changing the ownership from "`nobody`" to "`vobadm`"

Comment: I did describe on the vob and this is the output:

$ /usr/atria/bin/cleartool describe -l vob:/vobs/***
versioned object base "/vobs/***"

  created 2006-11-13T13:04:28+01:00 by Clearcase Admin  (***)
  "Created at request of ***"
  master replica: lon_replica@/vobs/***
  replica name: prod_replicaVOB family feature level: 4
  VOB storage host:pathname "***"
  VOB storage global pathname "***"
  database schema version: 54
  modification by remote privileged user: allowed
  atomic checkin: disabled
  VOB ownership:
    owner nobody
    group app_ccase_prod
  Attributes:
    FeatureLevel = 4

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting. Can't upload the output in more friendly way.

Comment: @RadoslawWitkowicki If you are on unix, try making your command as root: root is a privilege user.

Comment: The problem that I can not login as root - huge restrictions. Is there any way to do it without root access. I have checked with sys admin (root) and he could run the command witout any problems.

Comment: @VobC Do you think that change ownership of the vob from nobody to vobadm could help?

Comment: @RadoslawWitkowicki it would certainly help, yes. Only root can do it though. And make sure your ClearCase admin is aware of the replaicated nature of that vob.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to inform that the issue was resolved. I have  changed the ownership, from "nobody" to "vobadm".

Comment: @Radek Great! i have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.